# Spring Boot Web - Modifying response before committed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, httpresponse, spring-filter

I want to change the response of the controller after answer is returning (to create some type of encryption/decrytion).

I added filter and wrapped the HttpServletResponse, my issues are:

1. After changing the response i get the data truncated (usually 31 as the default value for the content-length), probably the length is not change since the response was committed.
2. Even if i can change the length of the buffer so it will not be truncated i can't, i know the length of my response only after it returns.
3. ResponseBodyAdvice not helping me too much since i need to know the type and i need to apply this filter on almost every api with different type, which means that the easiest way is to manipulate the response body as stream of bytes.

e.g.

for simplicity lets say that i want after calling getUser() the controller will not return "David" as the result but "RGF2aWQ=" (David in base64) - you can see here the the length is longer than the original

Thanks